# Run snippet tool like here on Stackoverflow?

Tags: json, console

Is there a tool that will take javascript and render it like the "Run snippet tool" here on stackoverflow?

i.e. instead of seeing something like this in the console:

```
▶[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
```

It would visually render it as json like this:

```
[{
  "one": 1
}, {
  "two": 2
}, {
  "three": 3
}, {
  "four": 4
}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) is often used to allow users executing Javascript code on your website. It's not the exactly the same as SO embedding, it opens a new tab with your code. You can read here on how to embed jsfiddle links http://doc.jsfiddle.net/use/embedding.html